# how to generate ERD from LoopBack model file

Tags: node.js, database, loopbackjs, erd, loopback4

How can I convert LoopBack 4 models into ERD?

**NOTE:** It doesn't matter if there is an independent tool of VSCode extension.

Comment: I found [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-erd) generator for sequelize ORM but I couldn't find any solution for LB ORM